# Why I can't install Elementary OS on HP laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, laptop, hp, error

Please, help me. I can't install this beautiful OS. |
My laptop: HP 250 G6 |
x64 |
RAM: 2x8 (16GB) |
CPU: i3-7020U |
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 620 |
SSD: 256GB |
HDD: 150GB |
Photo of Errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kfMo.jpg |
*and before I had more problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your installer was either corrupted, or your write to install media was flawed.
Check yout instalation media USB and try again.
More info:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SquashfsErrors
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236021/why-do-i-see-a-message-squashfs-errorunable-to-read-data-and-page-while-install

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solvation! I formatted the flash drive, after that I mounted the .ISO file, moved all files from .ISO to flash drive and booted through EFI (select the EFI file in ../EFI/boot/bootx64.efi) (Before I did it through basic Boot in USB with written 'elementary OS').

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to install Horus on my Dell Inspiron 7434 laptop. It burps with some obscure text and refuses to continue.  I've tried a myriad of ways to no avail.  Posted questions on all the various EOS sites with no response.